# Javascript multiple keys code

Tags: javascript, keyboard

How to get multiple keys code ?

i.e for `Ctrl+g` what is the key code ?

The key code for `ctrl` is `17` and for `g` is `71`. Should i use the key code `88 (17+71)` for `ctrl+g` ?

or for `shift+alt+1` etc

Any suggestions, is this possible ? I am using jquery and is there any plugin for this ?

☺☺☺☺

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) on the subject:

The event object yielded to your handler has a `ctrlKey` property.

So, e.g.: `if( e.keyCode == 71 && e.ctrlKey ) { // ctrl+g }`

Answer (score 6):

The `KeyboardEvent` object will have ctrlKey, shiftKey, altKey, and metaKey properties. Check that evt.ctrlKey is true. There's no need to use jQuery for this. See here for latest (DOM3) documentation: http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20060413/keyset.html#Modifiers